# Java Assignment, Flawed Logic

Tags: java

First off, I know that you guys dislike it when questions like these are asked however I'm unable to see what's wrong with my code and would like someone to look it over. With that said, I know my code looks terrible and that's because this has to be all done in one method.

```
public static int dayOfWeek(int year, int month, int day) {
    int monthCode = 0, centuryCode = 0, numLeapYears = 0, dayOfWeek = 0;

    int yearDigits = year % 100;

    if((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))) {
        numLeapYears = yearDigits / 2 + 1;
    }else {
        numLeapYears = yearDigits / 2;
    }

    if(((year >= 1400) && (year <= 1499)) || ((year >= 1800) && (year <= 1899)) || ((year >= 2200) && (year <= 2299))) {
        centuryCode = 2;
    }else if(((year >= 1500) && (year <= 1599)) || ((year >= 1900) && (year <= 1999)) || ((year >= 2300) && (year <= 2399))) {
        centuryCode = 0;
    }else if(((year >= 1600) && (year <= 1699)) || ((year >= 2000) && (year <= 2099)) || ((year >= 2400) && (year <= 2499))) {
        centuryCode = 5;
    }else if(((year >= 1700) && (year <= 1799)) || ((year >= 2100) && (year <= 2199)) || ((year >= 2500) && (year <= 2599))) {
        centuryCode = 4;
    }

    switch(month) {
        case 1: monthCode = 0;
        break;

        case 2: monthCode = 3;
        break;

        case 3: monthCode = 3;
        break;

        case 4: monthCode = 6;
        break;

        case 5: monthCode = 1;
        break;

        case 6: monthCode = 4;
        break;

        case 7: monthCode = 6;
        break;

        case 8: monthCode = 2;
        break;

        case 9: monthCode = 5;
        break;

        case 10: monthCode = 0;
        break;

        case 11: monthCode = 3;
        break;

        case 12: monthCode = 5;
        break;
    }

    dayOfWeek = ((centuryCode + yearDigits + numLeapYears + monthCode + day) % 7);
    return dayOfWeek;
}//dayOfWeek
```

I haven't bothered to comment my code yet, the purpose of this function is to calculate the date of which a day falls on (Sunday, Monday, etc.) represented by a number (0, 1, 2, etc.) My code works, however it doesn't output the correct number. For instance 7/20/1969 is supposed to come out as 0, but my code outputs 3. I can't seem to find the flaw in my logic for this method.

Comment: what is numLeapYears supposed to represent? Is it how many leap years that have occured since todays date? Why are you yearDigits/2?

Comment: How have you decided your `centuryCode` and `monthCode`??

Comment: numLeapYears is supposed to be the number of leapYears since the beginning of the century.

Edit: That was my problem, thanks for helping me realize it.

Comment: I can't tell if you are just an inexperienced programmer or if you're trolling us? If it is just inexperience, I would love to help but can you walk us through your algorithm? Seriously, if this logic works, can you take me through your process and what MonthCode and Century code are?

Comment: Then shouldn't it be `yearDigits / 4`??

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't just use the Calendar class for that? cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)

Comment: I just realized that there is a function to do all of this for me, which would of saved me about 45 minutes of work.

I got this algorithm from: http://www.jimloy.com/math/day-week.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch on the month looks off - calendar indexes months starting at 0. Therefore `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == 0` for dates in January.

With that said, you've provided no explanation for what `monthCode` should represent, which makes it really hard to offer any type of help.